# Problem embedding user_register_form in custom template

Tags: 7, forms, users

I need to embed the user_register_form inside a template.

In my module i do:

```
....
$form=drupal_get_form("user_register_form");
unset($form["field_nickname"]);
unset($form["locale"]);
$output=theme("agent_new",array("element"=>array("form"=>$form, "var1"=>$var1, "var2"=>$var2)));
```

I specify "agent_new" in hook_theme and in agent_new.tpl.php:

```
<div>
   <?php print drupal_render($element["form"]["field_first_name"]); ?>
</div>
<div>
   <?php print drupal_render($element["form"]["field_surname"]); ?>
</div>
...
<?php print drupal_render_children($element["form"]); ?>
```

The problem is that  the <form> tag is not rendered and i need to insert it manually, i think this is not a good thing.

Where is the mistake? Do i need to directly theme the user_register_form ? Is it not possible to embed it in my theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

In your `.module` file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // User Register
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    unset($form["field_nickname"]);
    unset($form["locale"]);
  }
}
```

In your `.tpl.php` file:

```
<?php
if (!$logged_in):
  $elements = drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
  $rendered = drupal_render($elements);
  $output  = '<form action="' . $elements['#action'] . '" method="' . $elements['#method'] . '" id="' . $elements['#id'] . '" accept-charset="UTF-8">';
  // Your required fields here!
  $output .= $elements['name']['#children'];
  $output .= $elements['pass']['#children'];
  $output .= $elements['form_build_id']['#children'];
  $output .= $elements['form_id']['#children'];
  $output .= $elements['actions']['#children'];    
  $output .= $elements['links']['#children'];
  $output .= '</form>';
  print $output;
endif;
?>
```